# A Copy Paste Fail Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the code I used (triggered by a button on the "Sorts" worksheet):

```
Sub EOS_Archive_2()
Dim LCopyRow As Long
Dim LDistRow As Long
 
LCopyRow = Worksheets("Sorts").Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
LDistRow = Worksheets("Sorts Archive").Cells(Sheet10.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 
Worksheets("Sorts").Range("C2: H" & LCopyRow).Copy _
Destination:=Worksheets("Sorts Archive").Range("B" & LDistRow)
 
End Sub
```

Here are the sheets I am copying from and to:

[image: Sheet2 - "Sorts"]

"Door" is in cell B1. The above sheet is "Sorts" It is desired to copy C2 through Hn (n being the last row of data in the range)

[image: Sheet10 - "Sorts Archive"]
The above sheet is "Sorts Archive" and this is the result of my code. Should paste the values into columns B through G. The code is run at the end of each day and will build data in the Sorts Archive sheet. All pasted data should start after the last row of data.

[image]

The above shows what the expected and desired result should be. Not sure why I am not getting the desired result. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: `LCopyRow = Worksheets("Sorts").Cells(Worksheets("Sorts").Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: If "Door" is in column B: What is in column A? If it is empty, `LCopyRow` will have a wrong value (you are checking column A for the last row). You should use the debugger to check what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Col A on `Sorts` sheet has only a used cell (A1), that is `LCopyRow  = 1`. That's the reason why only one row is copied over.
- Please qualify `Rows.Count` with same sheet object.
- You should locate the last data row by col 2 on both sheets.

```
LCopyRow = Worksheets("Sorts").Cells(Worksheets("Sorts").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    
LDistRow = Worksheets("Sorts Archive").Cells(Worksheets("Sorts Archive").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

Comment: Thank you. Total brain fart. Thank you for the assist!

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code

```
Sub EOS_Archive_2()
Dim LCopyRow As Long
Dim LDistRow As Long
 
LCopyRow = Worksheets("Sorts").Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
LDistRow = Worksheets("Sorts Archive").Cells(Sheet10.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 
Worksheets("Sorts").Range("C2:H" & LCopyRow).Copy
Worksheets("Sorts Archive").Range("B" & LDistRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
 
End Sub
```